# Symfony - keeps forcing login despite security settings

Tags: php, jquery, web-services, symfony

I have a webservice that I want people to be able to access without logging in or getting a login page. That page is `/webservice/access`

These are my security settings:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/_wdt, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } # No need for login
    - { path: ^/users/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/allviewer/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/items/edit/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/webservice/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } # No need for login
```

I'm looking at the network tab in Chrome though, just after I make a jQuery POST call to the `webservice/access` page. I'm seeing `access` come up, with a 302 status (found). But straight after that I'm getting `login` with a 200 OK message.

I don't understand why it's doing this. If I use RESTCLIENT Firefox extension to post data to the same page it works fine.

The jQuery call is like this:

```
var accessData = $.post(postLink, postData, function() { ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you clear the cache ?

Comment: I tried that - it's not the cache

Comment: May be this is because, you can't make a cross-domain AJAX call without using JSONP, it's forbidden by the same origin policy for security reasons. Is your request cross domain?

Comment: Try to place your ^/webservice/ before '^/' in your access_control configuration

Answer (score 0):

Problem occurs here

```
 - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
 - { path: ^/webservice/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } # No need for login
```

you're telling to your firewall that all path are accessible only if user has `ROLE_USER` that, of course, isn't a `AUTHTENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` one.

Symfony2 firewall rules are parsed and matched exactly in the order you write it: `^/` path is matched before `^/webservice/` one so you'll never reach it.

My solution and suggestion is to switch them or, better, if you know for sure that `/webservice/` route will never require an authentication method, you can also move it at the top of your rules